# ¿Qué podría estar afectando la conexión? C#/SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy haciendo una práctica en MVC, con C# (VS 2015) y la conexión a una base de datos (SQL Server v17.2 Express), el problema que tengo es que en el Data Source el signo "\" no me lo está identificando:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-5NKCNPB\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
```

Aclaro algunos detalles:

1. La conexión es por medio de una Data Connection.
2. La conexión a la base de datos no me la identifica con el `"."`
3. La conexión a la base de datos solo funciona como en el ejemplo:

   ```
   "DESKTOP-5NKCNPB\SQLEXPRESS" O TAMBIÉN CON ".\SQLEXPRESS"
   ```

Comment: es porque la barra \ se utiliza para escapar caracteres. Si pones dos barras \\ el error se soluciona. Aprovecha y mira [ask] y tambien hace el [tour]

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi, la barra \ es para escapar caracteres especiales. Otra forma que tienes que hacerlo, a parte de la que te ha ofrecido el compañero, es poner @ antes de las comillas del string de conexión.

Comment: Comentas que no te reconoce el slash pero que error te marca? También recuerda si usas integrated security el pool le puedes poner a tipo servicio para que no tengas problemas o prueba usando sa o creando una nueva cuenta de sql. Y no te va reconocer la conexión poniendo . por que el sql que instalaste tiene nombre de instancia

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda, me sirvió de mucho sus comentarios.

Answer (score 4):

En **C#**, como en la mayoría de lenguajes de programación, indica una "[secuencia de escape](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp#Literales)", esto significa que va un caracter "no imprimible" como un retorno de carro (`\r`), nueva línea (`\n`), una tabulación (`\t`), incluso una alerta (`\a`).

Por lo tanto, al escribir una diagonal inversa `\` le indicas al compilador que irá un caracter para una secuencia de escape. La solución para poder escribir el caracter de la diagonal inversa es la siguiente secuencia:

```
"\\"
```

o para incluir unas comillas dobles `"` dentro de una cadena de texto, se utiliza

```
"\""
```

La solución para tu problema es *escapar* la diagonal inversa:

```
"Data Source=DESKTOP-5NKCNPB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True"
//                           ^ Aquí es donde ocurre la magia
```

Otra solución es usar una [Verbatim string](https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/verbatim-string-literal/). Su uso es muy sencillo, solo necesitas poner un `@` antes de la cadena y tomará la diagonal inversa `\` como un caracter normal. También te permitirá "partir" la cadena en líneas sin necesidad de usar los escapes para salto de línea o tabulador:

```
string verbatim = @"Esta es una cadena
válida para C# (que no en otros lenguajes)
por solo ponerle el @ antes. Se pueden usar    tabuladores
y saltos de línea, además de usar la diagonal inversa \ sin que se tome
como una secuencia de escape. Las comillas dobles se pueden escribir con dos
sucesivas así: "" y la cadena se termina como una cadena normal, con
*unas* comillas dobles.";
```

De esta manera, puedes escribir tu línea de conexión así:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-5NKCNPB\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True");
```